# Monge-Ampère equation and optimal transport

Tags: reference-request, optimal-transport

I'm a beginer in optimal transport, I'm looking for a reference about solving Monge-Ampère for discrete measure.

And if you have any reference for beginners, it's cool!

My background : Actually 4th university in maths :).

Thanks you !